# Distribute vertical spacing equally between two elements in one column using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have 3 columns each taking 3col width (bootstrap) and in each column there are two elements each after another. The first 3 top elements in those 3 columns are aligned vertically nicely but the bottom ones are in different positions because top ones are different height. If I give the items inside columns a fixed height like 300px then it works fine, but I want to know if there is any other way to achieve this without giving a specific height and using only flexbox?

[image]

```
<div class="gray_background">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
<section id="text-18" class="widget widget_text"><h2 class="widget-title">New and Refurbished Equipment</h2>            <div class="textwidget"></div>
        </section></div>

<div class="footer_widget col-lg-3 col-md-12">
  <section id="sole_source_main_widget_8-3" class="widget sole_source_main_widget_8"><h2 class="widget-title"> 


</h2><h4>Flexible Endoscopes</h4>

<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/gastroscopes/">Gastroscopes</a></h2>

<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/bronchoscopes/">Bronchoscopes</a></h2>

<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/colonoscopes/">Colonoscopes</a></h2>

<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/hysteroscopes/">Hysteroscopes</a></h2>

<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/small-diameter-ureteroscopes/">Small Diameter Ureteroscopes</a></h2>

<h2><a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/product/choledscopes/">Choledscopes</a></h2>



  </section>  <section id="sole_source_main_widget_8-5" class="widget sole_source_main_widget_8"><h2 class="widget-title"> .....
```

Comment: can you create a snippet with a working code ? so we better see the Structure you are using

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution :

Set a big-container in flex with `align-items: stretch;` so each column will have same heigth.

And then set `heigth:50%` to elements in your columns

I add a margin, it looks better

```css
.big-container
{
  display:flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.column
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex:1;
}

.column div
{
  height:calc(50% - 15px);
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <h2>col 1</h2>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>col 2</h2>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <div>
    <h2>col 3</h2>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div>
  <h2>col 4</h2>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>a</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div>
    <h2>col 5</h2>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>col 6</h2>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```